# using wbadmin to backup and recover

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

HI I am using wbadmin to perform backups of a specific folder, primarily to backup my VHD files

this is working fine but I tried to recover the files today using a different machine to the one which created the backup and couldnt get the machine doing the recovery to 'see' the backups.

Is there a  way to do this as my worry is that if I have a failure on the host which is perfmorming the backups I need to be able to install hyper-v on another host and recover the backed up VMs to there until I can rebuild the host.

It appears that this isnt possible, I am hoping I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> > couldnt get the machine doing the recovery to 'see' the backups.

Did you try assigning the backup drive a Drive Letter using Disk management (on the recovery machine) and then starting Windows Server Backup, selecting  Recover, Another Server, Local Drives?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the machine name is part of the wbadmin dump location so thats possibly why, on a different machine, that wbamin won't 'see' your backups. Not sure if restore to a different machine is supported.